# Remove element from ActiveRecord_Relation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can i remove the last element from an ActiveRecord_Relation in rails?

e.g. if I set:

```
@drivers = Driver.all
```

I can add a another Driver object called @new_driver to @drivers by doing:

```
@drivers << @new_driver
```

But how can I remove an object from @drivers?

The delete method doesn't seem to work, i.e.

```
@drivers.delete(0)
```

Comment: what is the association name ?

Comment: `@drivers.delete(@new_driver)` ?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify. I'm not looking to delete the object from the DB, only from the collection. I'm using the collection as an option list within a form and am continually changing/updating it. Given this, I suppose neither the delete nor destroy methods are appropriate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `reject!` method, this will remove the object from the collection without affecting the db

for example:

```
driver_to_delete = @driver.first # you need the object that you want removed
@drivers.reject!{|driver| driver == driver_to_delete}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer seems to work in Rails 6.1 – I'm not sure when this changed, but here's the error message: `NoMethodError: undefined method `reject!' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation […]`

Comment: @Marc and @cousine please check my answer to understand why `reject!` cannot work.

Answer (score 6):

Very late too, but I arrived here looking for a fast answer and finished by thinking by myself ;)

Just to clarify about the different answers and the Rails 6.1 comment on accepted answer:

The OP wanted to **remove** one entry from a query, but NOT remove it from database, so any answer with `delete` or `destroy` is just wrong (this WILL delete data from your database !!).

In Ruby (and therefore Rails) convention, shebang methods (ending with `!`) tend to alter the given parameter. So `reject!` would imply modifying the source list ... but an `ActiveRecord_Relation` is basically just a **query**, NOT an array of entries !

---

So you'd have 2 options:

- Write your query differently to specifically say you don't want some id:

```rb
@drivers.where.not(id: @driver_to_remove)  # This still is an ActiveRecord_Relation
```

- Use `reject` (NO shebang) on your query to transform it into an Array and "manually" remove the entry you don't want:

```rb
@drivers.reject{ |driver| driver ==  @driver_to_remove}
# The `reject` forces the execution of the query in DB and returns an Array)
```

---

On a **performance** point of view, *I would personally recommend the first solution* as it would be just a little more complex against the DB where the latter implies looping on the whole (eventually large) array.

Answer (score 4):

Late to the question, but just had the same issue and hope this helps someone else.

`reject!`did not work for ActiveRecord_Relation in Rails 4.2

`drop(1)` was the solution

In this case `@drivers.drop(0)` would work to drop the first element of the relation

Comment: but one thing i noticed is that class of collection will become an Array and other Active Record Relation methods cannot be used.

Answer (score 1):

Since its an array of objects, have you tried to write something like @drivers.delete(@new_driver) or @drivers.delete(id: @new_driver.id) ?

Comment: Warning: This deletes the record from the database! It's quite unexpected because on a normal array that would indeed do what you'd expect. But on an ActiveRecord collection it will execute a DELETE statement.

Answer (score 1):

[This is the documentation you need](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html):

```
@group.avatars << Avatar.new
@group.avatars.delete(@group.avatars.last)
```

--

**`.destroy`**

The problem you've got is you're trying to use `collection` methods on a non-collection object. You'll need to use the `.destroy` ActiveRecord method to get rid of the record from the database (and consequently the collection):

```
@drivers = Driver.all
@drivers.last.destroy
```

--

**Scope**

`.delete` will remove the record from the DB

If you want to pull specific elements from the db to populate the `@drivers` object, you'll need to use a [`scope`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes):

```
#app/models/driver.rb
Class Driver < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :your_scope, -> { where column: "value" }
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
#app/controllers/drivers_controller.rb
def index
   @drivers = Driver.your_scope
end
```

I think you're getting the [MVC programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) confused - data manipulation is meant to happen in the `model`, not the `controller`

Comment: Sorry, to clarify. I'm not looking to delete the object from the DB, only from the collection. I'm using the collection as an option list within a form and am continually changing/updating it. Given this, I suppose neither the delete nor destroy methods are appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, `reject!` doesn't work in Rails 4.2, but delete does, so `@drivers.delete(@new_driver)` works, and more generally:

```
@drivers.delete(Driver.where(your condition))
```